# ‘‘TCA_HTB_PAD’ undeclared’ undeclared

Tags: kernel

I was trying to build the kernel with a new package called kaunetem included in the kernel tree. I got the following error when compiling. I do not think it has occured due to the kaunetem package as it does not contain `TCA_HTB_PAD` .

```
net/sched/sch_htb.c: In function ‘htb_dump_class’:
net/sched/sch_htb.c:1098:10: error: ‘TCA_HTB_PAD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
TCA_HTB_PAD))

net/sched/sch_htb.c:1098:10: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
scripts /Makefile.build:295: recipe for target 'net/sched/sch_htb.o' failed

make[2]: *** [net/sched/sch_htb.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:440: recipe for target 'net/sched' failed
make[1]: *** [net/sched] Error 2
Makefile:968: recipe for target 'net' failed

make: *** [net] Error 2
Command exited with non-zero status 2
```

Comment: Please edit your post and format it properly, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help.

Comment: Hi, I have formated. Please let me know if this is fine