# Error: TCA_HTB_PAD undeclared while building kernel

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, compiling, make

I was trying to build the kernel [following this tutorial](https://kernelnewbies.org/KernelBuild) (I'm on Ubuntu). When executing the "make" command, I got an error:

```
net/sched/sch_htb.c: In function ‘htb_dump_class’:
net/sched/sch_htb.c:1115:10: error: ‘TCA_HTB_PAD’ undeclared (first use in this function)
          TCA_HTB_PAD))
          ^
net/sched/sch_htb.c:1115:10: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
scripts/Makefile.build:300: recipe for target 'net/sched/sch_htb.o' failed
make[2]: *** [net/sched/sch_htb.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:553: recipe for target 'net/sched' failed
make[1]: *** [net/sched] Error 2
Makefile:1002: recipe for target 'net' failed
make: *** [net] Error 2
```

This error has already been reported on this link (I also build this kernel for kaunetem): [‘‘TCA_HTB_PAD’ undeclared’ undeclared](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318759/tca-htb-pad-undeclared-undeclared) but the user had no answer to his problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was due to the kernel compatibility issue for the package that I was using. When I used kernel 4.5, it was okay.

Comment: It's a little unclear what your answer means. Are you saying that you encountered the same error as OP and found a fix? If so you might want to specify that clearly as well as provide additional details (What package were you using? What version failed? Etc.)

Comment: I was building the kernel with some additional tools into the kernel. That tools did not had support for kernel 4.7 and it was supported till kernel 4.5 only.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question